# Populate CollectionView and TableView using objects at different index of same array

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, tableview, xcode9

I want to show Products of "group_type" == 1 in CollectionView and Products of "group_type" == 2 in TableView.

I want to populate TableView in order where "group_title" will be Section Header and Products in Array "Products" as Rows.
Below is my JSON.

What Swift code do I need?

```
  "product_groups": [
    {
        "group_title": "Recommended",
        "group_type": 1,
        "products": [
            {
                "product_id": 1,
                "product_name": "Product 1",
                "product_price": "Rs 1,999/-",
                "product_category": "Equipment & Chairs",
                "product_image": "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/products/product_1.jpg",
                "product_description": "Description 1"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 2,
                "product_name": "Product 2",
                "product_price": "Rs 1,999/-",
                "product_category": "Equipment & Chairs",
                "product_image": "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/products/product_1.jpg",
                "product_description": "Description 1"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 3,
                "product_name": "Product 3",
                "product_price": "Rs 1,999/-",
                "product_category": "Equipment & Chairs",
                "product_image": "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/products/product_1.jpg",
                "product_description": "Description 1"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 4,
                "product_name": "Product 4",
                "product_price": "Rs 1,999/-",
                "product_category": "Equipment & Chairs",
                "product_image": "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/products/product_1.jpg",
                "product_description": "Description 1"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 5,
                "product_name": "Product 5",
                "product_price": "Rs 1,999/-",
                "product_category": "Equipment & Chairs",
                "product_image": "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/products/product_1.jpg",
                "product_description": "Description 1"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 6,
                "product_name": "Product 6",
                "product_price": "Rs 1,999/-",
                "product_category": "Equipment & Chairs",
                "product_image": "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/products/product_1.jpg",
                "product_description": "Description 1"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 7,
                "product_name": "Product 7",
                "product_price": "Rs 1,999/-",
                "product_category": "Equipment & Chairs",
                "product_image": "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/products/product_1.jpg",
                "product_description": "Description 1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "group_title": "Offers",
        "group_type": 2,
        "products": [
            {
                "product_id": 8,
                "product_name": "Product 8",
                "product_price": "Rs 1,999/-",
                "product_category": "Materials & Consumables",
                "product_image": "",
                "product_description": "Description 1"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 9,
                "product_name": "Product 9",
                "product_price": "Rs 1,999/-",
                "product_category": "Materials & Consumables",
                "product_image": "",
                "product_description": "Description 1"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 10,
                "product_name": "Product 10",
                "product_price": "Rs 1,999/-",
                "product_category": "Materials & Consumables",
                "product_image": "",
                "product_description": "Description 1"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 11,
                "product_name": "Product 11",
                "product_price": "Rs 1,999/-",
                "product_category": "Materials & Consumables",
                "product_image": "",
                "product_description": "Description 1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "group_title": "Hot Selling",
        "group_type": 2,
        "products": [
            {
                "product_id": 12,
                "product_name": "Product 12",
                "product_price": "Rs 1,999/-",
                "product_category": "Instruments",
                "product_image": "",
                "product_description": "Description 1"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 13,
                "product_name": "Product 13",
                "product_price": "Rs 1,999/-",
                "product_category": "Instruments",
                "product_image": "",
                "product_description": "Description 1"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 14,
                "product_name": "Product 14",
                "product_price": "Rs 1,999/-",
                "product_category": "Instruments",
                "product_image": "",
                "product_description": "Description 1"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 15,
                "product_name": "Product 15",
                "product_price": "Rs 1,999/-",
                "product_category": "Instruments",
                "product_image": "",
                "product_description": "Description 1"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 16,
                "product_name": "Product 16",
                "product_price": "Rs 1,999/-",
                "product_category": "Instruments",
                "product_image": "",
                "product_description": "Description 1"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Have you written any Swift code for this yet? If not, please do so first before asking a question. Readers want to help you, but they do not wish to take on free work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter method of array:

```
//this filter will return you all objects whose group type is equal to 1
let collectionArray = (product_groups?.filter({$0.group_type == 1})) 
//this filter will return you all objects whose group type is equal to 2
let tableArray = (product_groups?.filter({$0.group_type == 2}))
```

For group title to be section header:

```
- (nullable NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      return tableArray[section].group_title
}
```

For products to display in each cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      //cell code...
      cell.titleLabel.text = tableArray[indexPath.section][indexpPath.row].product_name
      // cell code
}
```

Comment: Showing error at : {$0.group_type == 1}

Comment: Can you please post error?

Comment: Value of type 'Any' has no member 'group_type' and Cast 'Any' to 'AnyObject' or use 'as!' to force downcast to a more specific type to access members

Comment: Ohh, I think you have not made Model Classes for this JSON. I assumed, you have mapped this json data & you have made models for this json data.

Comment: Try to make Data Model Classes for this json. if any issue, post here.

Comment: Type 'Product_groups?' has no member 'filter' why this error now ? I've made Model Classes for complete json

Comment: 'product_groups' here is assumed to be array! it will be the root array return to you in json.

Comment: public class Product_groups {
 public var group_title : String?
 public var group_type : Int?
 public var products : Array<Products>?
................................. } Product_groups is the name of the class.

Comment: Go via this to find proper format of your json: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=8f2968514d61ac3aa7bcb4ed1036d3a3

Comment: okay, can you please share code for when you get response from server, how do you get it and how do you save the response object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157454/discussion-between-shikha-sharma-and-baig).

Comment: That would be more better.