# Get value from a mapped array by Alamofire Object Mapper Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, objectmapper

Below is my code I used to map my JSON using Object Mapper, I successfully filtered arrays.

```
 Alamofire.request("https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/v2.0/company/1", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: params).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<ProductGroup>) in
        let ProductGroupRes = response.result.value

        if let Product = ProductGroupRes?.products
        {    
            self.collectionArray = Product.filter({$0.group_type == 1}) as NSArray
            print(self.collectionArray)

            self.tableArray = Product.filter({$0.group_type == 2}) as NSArray


        }

    }
```

This is my filtered array i.e. `collectionArray`

```
"IndiaSupply.Product(group_title: Optional(\"Recommended\"), 
group_type: Optional(1), 
products: Optional([IndiaSupply.ProductArray(
         product_id: Optional(1), 
         product_name: Optional(\"Product 1\"),
         product_price: Optional(\"Rs 1,999/-\"), 
         product_category: Optional(\"Surgical\"),
         product_image: Optional(\"\"),
         product_description: Optional(\"Description 1\")),
        IndiaSupply.ProductArray(product_id: Optional(2),
         product_name: Optional(\"Product 2\"),
         product_price: Optional(\"Rs 1,999/-\"), 
         product_category: Optional(\"Surgical\"), 
         product_image: Optional(\"\"), 
         product_description: Optional(\"Description 1\")),
         IndiaSupply.ProductArray(product_id: Optional(3), 
         product_name: Optional(\"Product 3\"), 
         product_price: Optional(\"Rs 1,999/-\"),
         product_category: Optional(\"Surgical\"), 
         product_image: Optional(\"\"),
         product_description: Optional(\"Description 1\")),
      IndiaSupply.ProductArray(product_id: Optional(4),
       product_name: Optional(\"Product 4\"), 
       product_price: Optional(\"Rs 1,999/-\"), 
       product_category: Optional(\"Surgical\"), 
       product_image: Optional(\"\"), 
       product_description: Optional(\"Description 1\")),

          )
```

How I can fetch array of products from this result, and then get value from it. I couldn't fetch it with this code:

```
let Pro = self.collectionArray.value(forKey : "products") as NSArray
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions. **I have downvoted this time** since [I have asked this before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46924727/472495).

Answer (score 1):

Its great you mapped it successfully, now you have to just use these model objects like,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   //....
   let aProduct = self.collectionArray[indexPath.item] as! Product
   cell.labelName.text = aProduct.product_name
   //and so on

}
```

Comment: No still can't access product_name, I can only access group_title and group_type

Comment: Can you please share your code with me, so that i can review it faster.

Comment: share your email ?

Comment: @Baig: while the community cannot prevent helpers sharing their private contact details if they really wish to, we prefer for it not to happen. The community benefits if all help can be done (and shown) publicly. Thanks!